# How to extract photos from JPG with white background?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, command-line-interface

I have a JPG file which contains multiple photos over a white background.

I'm looking for a CLI tool which can extract photos from the source JPG (without supplying coordinates) into separate JPG files maintaining quality and photo resolution.

From some research I suspect ImageMagick can achieve this though unsure of the correct CLI command.

If useful, I'm on OSX 10.13.2 and have ImageMagick 7.0.7-28 installed.

[image: Image extraction example]

Comment: I have two bash unix shell scripts using Imagemagick, multicrop or multicrop2, that will do that. The former searches a grid for the images. The latter each contiguous region for the images. Both should work. See  http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. They can be run on Windows only in Unix environment such as Windows 10 built-in Unix or Cygwin. They can be run also via PHP exec(). You can also do that by converting all non-white to black and then using Imagemagick's -connected-components command to find the black regions and then crop your original at those bounding boxes.

Comment: CONTINUED: What is your Imagemagick version and platform?

Comment: @fmw42 updated question with OS and Imagemagick version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do this in Unix using Imagemagick. I just cropped out your base image from your diagram, since I was not sure it that was part of your image or not. If it is part of the image, then you would have to trim that off first using -trim.

Input:

[image]

The first is my script, multicrop2:

(-f 10 is the fuzz factor for extracting the background)

(-u 3 means no attempt to unrotated the results)

```
multicrop2 -f 10 -u 3 image.jpg resulta.jpg

Processing Image 0
Initial Crop Box: 113x84+81+89

Processing Image 1
Initial Crop Box: 113x67+144+10

Processing Image 2
Initial Crop Box: 113x66+10+11
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

The second is using Imagemagick -connected-componets (which is what I use in my script)

What this does is:

```
1) fuzzy flood fill the background to transparent (since jpg is loss and does not preserve a uniform background.
2) change the color under the transparent to white and remove the transparency
3) change anything not white to black
4) apply -connected-components to throw out areas smaller than 400 pixel area and extract each bounding box and color
5) if the color is gray(0), i.e. black, then crop the original image to the bounding box and save to disk


OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`convert image.jpg -fuzz 10% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" \
-background white -alpha background -alpha off \
-fill black +opaque white -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=400 \
-connected-components 4 null: | tail -n +2 | sed 's/^[ ]*//'`)
IFS=$OLDIFS
num=${#arr[*]}
j=0
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
bbox=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f2`
color=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d\  -f5`
if [ "$color" = "gray(0)" ]; then
convert image.jpg -crop $bbox +repage resultb_$j.jpg
j=$((j+1))
fi
done
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT: Add processing of your actual image

Input:

[image]

The first thing to note is that your actual two images are right at the right side, but there is a black edge there. Also one at the top. That black edge connects the two image so that they cannot easily be separated by the multicrop2 script. So you need to shave off the right side by enough pixels to remove that edge. There is also the edge at the top and you can shave that off if you want. If you do, you can reduce the -d argument. The -d argument needs to be smaller that the area of the smallest image you want to extract and larger than any other minor noise or the stripe at the top in area. So I clip off 20 pixels from the right side and then use multicrop2 with a very large value for -d. I have chosen a value for -f of 8, which is seems to be in a rather narrow range due to the non-constant background. You can add -m save to look at the mask the script creates to see that you get a good separation between your two images. I seed the processing at -c 20,20 to avoid the black border at the top of your image, so that the script gets a good measure of the background color for the flood fill step.

```
convert test.jpeg -gravity east -chop 20x0 tmp.png
multicrop2 -c 20,20 -f 8 -d 100000 tmp.png result.jpg

Processing Image 0
Initial Crop Box: 2319x1627+968+2153

Processing Image 1
Initial Crop Box: 2293x1611+994+436
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @fmw42, unfortunately i'm not having much luck with the real-life case. Have been tweaking the command params but getting nowhere fast. eg. trying to extract the following photos - https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qh1vg7mw2m197p/test.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: For future reference it is always better to add actual example rather than "something like". File resolution will change as you are saving as jpg. There would be less loss if your original images were of a better format than jpg. You may be having problems as two of your edges have black borders. I assume you can not rescan the photos?

Comment: I have modified my answer to show an example of using multicrop2 with your newly provided actual input image.

Comment: im using a simpler convert command: `convert input.png -blur 20x20 -threshold 99% -define connected-components:verbose=true -define connected-components:mean-color=true -define connected-components:area-threshold=400 -connected-components 4 null:` - see also [Convert a greyscale image to 1-bit black/white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297092/convert-a-greyscale-image-to-1-bit-black-white-with-definable-threshold-maintai)