# Convert a greyscale image to 1-bit black/white with definable threshold, maintaining transparency?

Tags: command-line, graphics, imagemagick-convert

How can I convert a greyscale image to 1-bit black/white with definable threshold, but maintaining existing transparency/alpha?

> Existing questions miss out the transparency part of my question.

Also, I need to do this on the command-line in macOS. ImageMagick's `convert` is one option, but not the only option.

Sample image:
[image: greyscale image]

Required behaviour:

1. pixels below a definable threshold are coloured black
2. pixels above a definable threshold are coloured white
3. transparent pixels remain untouched

I prepared this "goal" image manually:

[image: goial]

What I have tried:

1. `$ convert -threshold 50% in.png out.png`

   - everything over threshold becomes white
   - everything below the threshold becomes transparent!
2. `$ convert -white-threshold 50% in.png out.png`

   - everything over threshold becomes white
   - everything below the threshold becomes transparent!
3. `$ convert -black-threshold 50% in.png out.png`

   - everything over a different threshold becomes white
   - nothing becomes black!
4. `$ convert +dither -monochrome in.png out.png`

   - dithering disabled
   - 1-bit conversion locked to 50% but performs as expected
   - but: transparent pixels are turned black!
5. `$ convert -depth 1 -colors 3 -alpha set in.png out.png`

   - almost there
   - but: threshold not definable!

Any thoughts appreciated!

Image Ref: http://www.studentshow.com/gallery/6097929/Pyramid-Module-Value-Grayscale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on IM 6.9.11.34 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra.

[image]

```
convert in.png -colorspace gray -channel rgb -threshold 50% +channel out.png
```

(In the above, you specify that the threshold should be applied only to the rgb channels and not the alpha via -channel rgb. After the threshold, I turn on all the channels again)

[image]

Comment: Ace! Could you please explain the reasoning?

Comment: I can understand the arguments, perfect solution! Thank you.